# Typescript doesn't infer value of generic object

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

Consider this function, it iterates over the provided object's keys and sets each key to a number and then returns the object. For some reason, typescript doesn't infer that obj[key] value is a number, I'm getting the following error:

> Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.ts(2322)

Does anyone know how to fix this? Parameter should always be be `Record<string, number>`.

```
function setObjKeysToOne<T extends Record<string, number>>(obj: T) {
  (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>).forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = 1; // Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.ts(2322)
  });

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need it generic at all? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQPICMBWBpVAT2QBU4MxUAKOXALkQCVUI4AnAEwB5ko2YwAcwA0iMCAC2WVGwB8ASkQBvAFCJEwdoiqswvRAGsiiOMETYcLKADojxGrnmLV69bRwBtOwF1EAXkQARgBuNUQAXxUwtnQQNiR3UPCgA)

Comment: Yes I do need it, this is not real-world code, I created it to illustrate the problem, In reality I need a generic there.

Comment: Without more of a use case I'd be wary of this sort of code, though.  That signature doesn't need to be generic, and if `T` is narrower than `Record<string, number>`, such as `{a: 123, b: 456}` where the properties are [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) then you *want* the compiler to complain about setting its properties to `1`.

Comment: @jcalz I see the problem here, but I just want to make sure that values are numbers, I don't care whether they are literal or not. I guess typecasting is the only way here. In the real-life code I set the values to `0` when a certain condition is met if that makes more sense, this is a contrived example.

Answer (score 1):

you could cast the obj during the assignment e.g.

```
function setObjKeysToOne<T extends Record<string, number>>(obj: T) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    (obj as Record<string, number>)[key] = 1;
  });

  return obj;
}
```

there's a related issue on github with an [explanation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31661#issuecomment-497138929) why typescript behaves that way.